# Newbie - Blank pdf using CodeIgniter and mPDF

Tags: codeigniter, view, mpdf

I'm new to CodeIgniter and even newer to mPDF and I'm having some brain trouble in trying to create a single-page invoice from an existing View. Code is as follows:

```
$this->load->library('mpdf');

$to_convert = $this->load->view('test_pdf_view',TRUE);

$this->mpdf->WriteHTML($to_convert);

$this->mpdf->Output();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `TRUE` as the third parameter to the view:

```
$to_convert = $this->load->view('test_pdf_view', NULL, TRUE);
```

Comment: Yes!  Thank you - that does the trick. There are still some parts of the document missing but I suspect that is because it is formatted using Bootstrap and mPDF is getting confused. Thanks again :-)